# The grammatically correct form

Tags: grammaticality, conditional-constructions

What is the grammatically correct form for this sentence?

> I would try(again) if I think it works.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on what idea you want to convey.

**Conditional**:

> If I **thought** it worked, I **would** try again.

Which, in a way, means that you won't try again because you don't think it works. For instance, in a discussion with a friend:

> Why are you not trying again dude ?
>
> Trust me, If I thought it worked, I would try again.

(Note: in an oral discussion, you could even emphasize **would** in order to better convey the idea that "in an hypothetical world where I thought it would be possible, I **would** indeed try again).

**Future**:

> I **will** try again if I **think** it works.

Takes place in the future. If you happen to think it could work in the near future, then you'll definitely try it again.

For more read on the subject, see: [Sequence of tenses](http://www.englishpractice.com/improve/sequence-tenses/)

Answer (score 0):

What do you need the bracket in the sentence? 'I would try again if I think it works.' is not incorrect. 'I would try again if I think it will work' is possibly a little better.

Comment: How about "I would try if I thought it would work", "I would try if I thought it works" or "I would try if I thought it will work"?